# Tumblr : How to display a specific URL if the image is a reblog

Tags: themes, tumblr

this is my first post here and I need some help with **Tumblr** theme customizing.

In my current theme, I have two icons showing under every image post. The first one links to the hyperlink entered when posting the image and the second one is a link to the post.

The thing is when it comes to reblogging an image without any hyperlink, the firsy icon leads to the homepage. I'd like to make it link to the orignal post when it's the case.

Here's the original code :

```
{block:Photo}
     <a href="{LinkURL}"><i class="icon-search"></i></a>
{/block:Photo}
<a href="{Permalink}"><i class="icon-link-1"></i></a>
```

Here's what I've tried :

```
{block:Photo}
     {block:IfLinkURL}<a href="{LinkURL}"><i class="icon-search"></i></a>{/block:IfLinkURL}
     {block:IfNotLinkURL}<a href="{ReblogURL}"><i class="icon-search"></i></a>{/block:IfNotLinkURL}
{/block:Photo}
```

But it doesn't work :(

Any idea?

Thanks a lot in advance

***Edit :*** I just found out that {ReblogURL} is a link to reblog the post. That's not what I want, I need a link to the post itself on the source blog.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your edit, I think you want: `{ReblogRootURL}`

> The URL for the blog this post was created by.

Source: http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#reblogs